eas build failed with Namespace 'androidx.versionedparcelable' is used in multiple modules
In react native expo app.
I run eas build --platform android.
The build went through but started to fail in run gradlew step after i upgraded expo to 52:

Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED
[androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1] /home/expo/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/e74c4937cd2099f316b2ffa87c1bebf3/transformed/versionedparcelable-1.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'androidx.versionedparcelable' is used in multiple modules and/or libraries: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1, com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0. Please ensure that all modules and libraries have a unique namespace. For more information, See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:28:18-86 Error:
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.13.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:18-86
is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:3-34:17 to override.
Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.

My package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.3",
"@expo-google-fonts/varela-round": "^0.2.3",
"@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^7.0.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.3.0",
"@tamagui/config": "^1.110.0",
"axios": "^1.7.9",
"expo": "~52.0.17",
"expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
"expo-font": "~13.0.1",
"expo-linking": "~7.0.3",
"expo-localization": "~16.0.0",
"expo-router": "~4.0.11",
"expo-secure-store": "~14.0.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.16",
"expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
"expo-system-ui": "~4.0.5",
"expo-updates": "~0.26.10",
"expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-dom": "18.3.1",
"react-native": "0.76.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
"react-native-iap": "^12.15.7",
"react-native-localize": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
"react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
"react-query": "^3.39.3",
"react-redux": "^9.1.2",
"tamagui": "^1.120.1"
}
I tried to upgrade all dependencies.

You should try running npx expo doctor.
It should fix the broken dependencies

the expo doctor tells tamagui and react native iap have not tested yet with the new expo architecture, but i can not replace those dependencies.
